# Forking and running dhclient (with params -nw -w) in exec creates a defunct process and a daemon process

Tags: c, signals, fork, exec

I am seeing a zombie process and the dhclient process when I fork from my parent process and then exec the dhclient process with its arguments

Here is the output

```
root     31298  0.0  0.0      0     0 pts/2    Z    09:22   0:00 [dhclientForData] <defunct>
root     31410  0.0  0.0  24260  9108 ?        Ss   09:23   0:00 -nw -w -sf etc/dhclient-script -pf /var/run/dhclient-vEth0.pid -lf /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient-vEth0.leases -cf /etc/sysconfig/dhclient.conf vEth0
```

I have renamed the linux system dhclient to dhclientForData in my parent process. Notice the second line in the above output I dont see the dhclient process name just the argurmnts I am not sure why, anyone?

my code

```
func_parent()
{
       pid_t child = 0;
        child = fork();
        if (child < 0)
        {   
            return 0;
        }
        if (child == 0)
        {   
            wanIntfDhclientHandlerProcessChildAdd ();
        }
        shmWlanTunMonitrConfig->childProcs[index].procId = child;
        sleep(1);
    }

    uint8_t wanIntfDhclientHandlerProcessChildAdd ()
    {
        pid_t mypid = getpid();
        uint8_t idx = gindex;
        //for (; idx < MAX_WAN_PORTS; idx++)
        {   
            if (!shmWlanTunMonitrConfig->childProcs[idx].isRunning && shmWlanTunMonitrConfig->childProcs[idx].cmdIdx != 0xFF)
            {   
                shmWlanTunMonitrConfig->childProcs[idx].isRunning = 1;

                char *const argV[] = {commands[idx].cmd[0],
                commands[idx].cmd[1],
                commands[idx].cmd[2],
                commands[idx].cmd[3],
                commands[idx].cmd[4],
                commands[idx].cmd[5],
                commands[idx].cmd[6],
                commands[idx].cmd[7],
                commands[idx].cmd[8],
                commands[idx].cmd[9],
                commands[idx].cmd[10],
                NULL};
                int ret = execvp(WAN_EXECUTABLE, argV);
    }
    }
    }
```

I have registered to the sigchld and will waitpid on that process. I have multiple processes running

```
pid_t pid = waitpid(shmWlanTunMonitrConfig->childProcs[index].procId, &status, WNOHANG);
```

I just delete the process from my parent process if the job is no longer required.

```
char cmd[512] = {0};
sprintf(cmd, "for KILLPID in `ps ax | grep \'/var/run/dhclient\' | grep \'%s\' | awk \' { print $1;}\'`; do kill -9 $KILLPID; done", portIntfAr[index].intfName);
system (cmd);
```

Can anyone please point me at what am I doing wrong.

Syed

Comment: when asking a question about a run time problem, as this question is doing. please post a [mcve] so we can recreate the problem so we can help you debug, it

Comment: the `exec*()` functions do NOT return unless and error occurred in starting the child process.  So the returned value can/should be totally ignored and follow the call with `perror( "execlp failed" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: OT: regarding `if (child < 0)
        {   
            return 0;`  when an error occurs the next two statements should be: `perror( "fork failed" );  exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`  Note a returned value of 0 (typically) indicates success, but. in reality,  the application has failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The zombie process `31298` exists as long as the parent process did not yet wait for it, so probably there is something wrong with your process table or your `waitpid` call.
I cannot check because your code is incomplete.

Instead of waiting for a specific PID you could also wait for any child or for a process group and find out from the resultuing `siginfo_t` structure which process just reported its state change.

I don't know which string you assign with

```
char *const argV[] = {commands[idx].cmd[0],
/* ... */
```

`argv[0]` should be the file name of the program, i.e. the same as `WAN_EXECUTABLE`

Comment: Thanks bodo, that helped. But I have a followup question. Since the dhclient is runnig in a daemon mode. it gets separated from the parent which means I do not have control over it anymore as it has it own process group. Is there a way to fix it and have the control over it all the time?

Comment: @SyedTowkhir What exactly do you want to do with the `dhclient` process? Why do you implement this as a C program? I think a shell script would be sufficient. If you don't want `dhclient` to run as a daemon you might omit the `-nw` option and add `-d` (Force dhclient to run as a foreground process.) if your `dhclient` supports this. (read `man dhclient`) You instruct `dhclient` to write its PID to a file. You can use the PID from the file to kill it instead of parsing the output of `ps`. `kill -9` should be used only if nothing else works. A killed program cannot save state or clean up.

Comment: I agree its a crude way. I will modify to use the pid file instead.